# Сгенерировать ETH адрес из private key

Tags: ethereum

Как узнать ETH Account Address зная только Private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берем приватный ключ (32 байта). Пусть это будет:

```
0x4040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040
```

Используя кривую `secp256k1` умножаем генератор на наш приватный ключ. Другими словами, получаем публичный ключ. Нам нужен результат (точка) в `uncompressed` формате. Получаем:

```
0x0450d1203e168650a52be58141df7b5be8e11f9c38e3ef76bffc9a8225039fcb97e9a96d2f85eddafdb1718ea1bbcc1795fb80a5bc0999e55fb50ae3089027744a
```

Исключаем первый байт (`0x04`, он всегда будет такой) и хешируем полученный остаток (64 байта) функцией `Keccak256`. Это `SHA-3`, но с немного другими изначальными параметрами. Получаем:

```
dd7063143807da6c79aecb72ee7e767e049143712099f92bc8a3b6b7f1b40335
```

Удаляем первые 12 байт, и получаем адрес:

```
0xee7e767e049143712099f92bc8a3b6b7f1b40335
```